# WP theme works on one server, but caused White Screen on another

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom theme (http://aspenwebsites.com/echo/) that works fine on a server here in US.

Today I attempted installing that theme to a server in Kazakhstan and got a White Screen - http://domstroy.kz/

Unfortunately I won't be able to access their database in order to change a selected theme or to their restore options for next 6-8 hours. I'm hoping to find the solution in the meantime while I only FTP access.

My custom theme was built as a modification to WP's Twenty-thirteen. I noticed their WP did not have Twenty-Thirteen WP theme present in the list of themes.  So I was hoping by bringing Twenty-Thirteen theme files over via FTP I might rescue the situation. It didn't seem to make any difference.

What else might it be or should I look for or try, since the very same theme works fine on a server here in US.

Comment: Renaming/removing the theme folder will make WordPress choose another one. As for the whitescreen issue, check the error logs.

Comment: I just read somewhere to check for file permissions. It turned out that all the theme files that were transferred via FTP were set to not be executable.   I went ahead and updated all the files of my  custom theme as well as Twenty-Thirteen to be readable, writable and executable.   Still having the White Screen.  I did flush my browser's memory, still the same. :/

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - thanks so much!!! It totally worked!! Still don't know what is wrong with the theme, but at least no longer getting the White Screen situation :)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - As far as viewing error log - is there a way to do so without the access to server? I only have an FTP login to the folder where WP was installed.

Comment: Only if the error logs are in your FTP accessible directory.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your theme from the theme folder using ftp. This should force WordPress to choose another one.

Are you running an up-to-date version of WordPress? If TwentyThirteen is missing, was it deleted or is the version of WordPress so old that it does not support TwentyThirteen? If the latter then your child theme won't work until you update WordPress and then put TwentyThirteen on, and then your theme.

HTH,

=C=

Comment: 1) Custom theme removed and I'm no longer getting White Screen.
2) WP is up to date. I do not know why Twenty-Thirteen isn't there, I wasn't the one who managed the site previously to this.

Comment: I just went ahead and added TwentyThirteen through WP Admin panel (located theme files in Theme's Search), then added my theme - still same Whit Screen once my custom theme is activated. 

I installed my theme on one of test sites I have hosted here in US - worked without any issues.